# Using 32 Bit Modules with Apache 86_64 Arch (64 bit)

Tags: php, apache, centos, odbc

So I have a very unique problem.

I am using php-ODBC (32 Bit) to connect to a remote ERP system.  This system is propitiatory and ONLY provides 32 bit ODBC drivers.

In order to use these drivers with PHP I MUST be using 32 bit php as well (unless someone knows a work around here to use 32 bit modules on PHP 86_64)

This means that I also need Apache 32 bit because unfortunately to my knowledge there is no way to run PHP 32 bit with Apache 64 bit..

Any help here would be appreciated, I tried compiling using

--with-libdir=lib32

but there are an infinite number of conflicts with Libtools

Comment: You could try using fastcgi. Then php can be it's own process (and it is more efficient anyway).

Comment: I also suggest you separate via fastcgi (or even cgi if you like). That decouples apache from PHP a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up reformatting the server with a 32bit OS.. Wasn't my preferred choice but under the time constraints it was all I had left.  I didn't try fastcgi, although this solution sound very plausible since it is it's own process.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Easysoft ODBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/index.html).

With this you could install a 32-bit ODBC-ODBC Bridge server which could connect to your ERP 32-bit ODBC Driver and a 64-bit ODBC-ODBC Bridge client which can connect to the 32-bit ODBC-ODBC Bridge server.

This is a commercial product where you can get a trial license. If you are planning on trying this contact Easysoft Support ( support@easysoft.com ) and ask them how to set this up.

Using this option would mean you could keep your defualt Apache & PHP both 64-bit but still access 32-bit ODBC data sources.